# Odoo 10 clickable button before setting mandatory fields in wizard

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I would like to create clickable button before setting mandatory fields in wizard that return grouped by product tree view.

[image]

Is the any possibilities to ignore mandatory fields and make clickable button?

xml:

```
<button string="Show quants from" name="button_show_quants_from" type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
```

python:

```
@api.multi
def button_show_quants_from(self):
    view = self.env.ref('my_stock.view_my_stock_quant_tree')
    self.ensure_one()
    return {
        'name': _('Quants from'),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree',
        'views': [(view.id, 'tree')],
        'view_id': view.id,
        'res_model': 'stock.quant',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target':'new',
        'domain': [('location_id','=',self.location_to_id.id),('reservation_id','=',False)],
    'context': {'group_by': 'product_id'},
    }
```

I was thinking about tree view inside this wizard form view but there I can't group it by product and the see messy view with lots of product quantity pieces.

Now I have one2many list like that:

[image]

Comment: What about using a computed many2many field? Just depend that on your location and compute your "grouped product lines". No button needed. And just make the list invisible when empty.

Comment: @CZoellner thank you for the suggestion. As I understand computed fields will be not saved in database. I was trying your example but there are some glitches. Don't understand how to submit so many computed product quantities into list. Because computed values are not saved into database so I don't have so many fields to submit products with computed quantities. Could you have any example I can analyze?

Comment: Hm when persistent entries are needed, then my solution isn't worth trying.